# Корректное удаление объекта потомка класса через указатель на базовый

Tags: c++, указатели, наследование, virtual

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Base 
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        cout << "~Base()\n";
    }
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    ~Child()
    {
        cout << "~Child()\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Base * p = new Child();

    delete p;          // так работает - это просто повезло или
                       // компилятор сам понимает как корректно удалить память?
    delete (Child*)p;  // лучше всегда явно приводить к типу указателя,
                       // для которого была выделена память?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае данное предложение

```
delete (Child*)p;
```

может привести к неопределенному поведению программы, так как заранее неизвестно, действительно ли указатель `p` указывает на производный класс. То есть при таком подходе нарушается полиморфизм.

Так как деструктор объявлен виртуальным, то нет никакой необходимости применять привдение типов. Достаточно написать

```
delete p;
```

при этом будет вызван деструктор того класса, который соответствует динамическому типу указателя, и будет вызвана та функции `delete`, которая использовалась при создании объекта динамического типа.

Answer (score 1):

Вы же сделали деструктор виртуальным, вот все у вас и получилось :)

Приведение указателя на базовый класс к указателю на производный класс в общем случае не самая разумная идея. Здесь она просто излишня - при виртуальном деструкторе (кстати, опять же в общем случае - при наличии наследования лучше делать деструктор виртуальным).

Comment: почему не самая лучшая идея?
если убрать vittual перед деструктором, то запись вида 
    delete (Child*)p;
корректно удалить память

Comment: Потому что это не единственная ситуация Например, представьте, что у вас есть (надуманно, конечно...) `void f(Base*p)`, в которой вы удаляете `p`. Или вызываете какую-то функцию - если вы сделаете ее не виртуальной, потребуется приведение. Но как вы будете выполнять приведение, даже не зная, что будет передано? А если это библиотечная функция? Да вы вообще можете в момент написания кода не знать о классе, указатель на который будете передавать - он еще может быть не то что не написан - еще и не задуман :) Этой аргументации достаточно или продолжать?...

Comment: это безусловный аргумент:) 
я немного неправильно поставил вопрос, когда мы делаем виртуальным деструктор базового класса, то получим корректное удаление при вызове  p->~Base();  так как лезем в таблицу виртуальных функций.
Я думал, что delete p; не будет этого делать, а просто посмотрит служебную информацию в начале выделенного блока памяти и удалит указанный размер

Comment: к примеру, if нет виртуального деструктора, то когда пишем 
'Base * p = new Child();'
'delete p;' <- вызовет только деструктор базового, а при вызове
'delete (Child*)p;'<- дочернего и базового.
if есть вирт деструтор, то будет корректное удаление с 'delete p;'
Т.е. delete сначала проверит есть ли вирт деструктор?

Comment: delete не только освобожждает память, но и *вызывает деструктор*. Но деструктор - фактически просто функция, не более того (правда, с вызовом других функций - деструктора базового класса, но это уже детали). И механизм вызова деструктора - по большому счету просто механизм вызова функции. Виртуальная? через vtable. Не виртуальная? Статически скомпилированный.

Comment: Да пожалуйста :) Можете даже отметить его как принятый, чтоб вопрос закрыть...